# private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer) doesn't run

Tags: c#, winapi, user32

I have the following code that seems to work on one of my projects but it doesn't work on a different one. Code is exactly the same on both but the method EnumWindow never gets
executed.

Here is the code:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Int32 GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder StrPtrClassName, Int32 nMaxCount);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr 

    public static List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle listHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
                listHandle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle gch = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }
        list.Add(handle);
        return true;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to get the all the childrens from iexplorer.exe process. The only difference between the two projects is that in one of them I am the one who opens manually an instance of IE and in the other one IE boots from the code.

In both cases, I am able to catch the right Process and the right main windows handle but no idea why in the second project I cannot get any children.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `DllImport` in your `EnumChildWindows` needs to be `user32.dll` not `user32`

Comment: I already changed and built my solution with user32.dll. It did not solve the problem though. Any other think could cause the issue?

Comment: I also noticed that I was able to use the EnumWindows to get a list of all the Windows Handles but I cannot use EnumChildWindows in the same way.

Comment: After debugging my code a bit deeper, I noticed that the EnumChildWindows is invoked properly. I noticed that the problem is that the Windows Handle that it is supposed to take from iexplorer is the wrong one! That is weird as there is only one iexplorer process running at the moment... any idea?

Comment: I found the solution :). Basically the iexplorer process had defined many different windows handlers. I had to use the EnumThreadWindows and get all the Windows Handler for that process. After that, just look for the Class Name I was interested in. Thanks!