# How do I get the handle of a child window in Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#

My problem is not being able to get the a flash child control inside Internet Explorer but I can do it within a webbrowser control. The webbrowser control is buggy with the flash object, so I need to do the work through Internet explorer and automate flash testing.

Below is the code for the webbrowser control which I am trying to replicate in IE 11.

```
private async Task<bool> clickCoorindate(Point point)
{
    IntPtr handle = null;
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }

    //webBrowser1.Focus();
    int x = point.X;
    int y = point.Y; 
    // IntPtr handle = webBrowser1.Handle;
    StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(100);
    while (className.ToString() != "MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX") 
    {
        handle = GetWindow(handle, 5); // Get a handle to the child window
        GetClassName(handle, className, className.Capacity);
    }

    IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x); // The coordinates
    IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero; // Additional parameters for the click (e.g. Ctrl)
    const uint downCode = 0x201; // Left click down code
    const uint upCode = 0x202; // Left click up code
    const uint moveCode = 0x200;

    SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button down
    SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button up
    Thread.Sleep(20);
    SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button down
    SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam); // Mouse button up

    return true;
}
```

When I use Spy++, the Flash object window is a child window of the IE window.

When I pass the IE mainwindow handle in the code above, it never finds the  MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX handle.

When testing this code in webbrowser control and passing the webbrowser control handle, it finds the flash object fine.

Any idea how to make this work with IE?

Someone asked a question similar here and found the solution, but unfortunately did not add it. 
[private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer) doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379238/private-static-bool-enumwindowintptr-handle-intptr-pointer-doesnt-run)

The solution comment from link above:

> I found the solution :). Basically the iexplorer process had defined many different windows handlers. I had to use the EnumThreadWindows and get all the Windows Handler for that process. After that, just look for the Class Name I was interested in.

Comment: You ignore all Exporer instances except the last one. Also you could use [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of all that.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work          **  Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
          IntPtr  hWnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "MyWeb - Internet Explorer");
            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                if (windowHandle == hWnd)
                     handle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX",null);

            
            }**    the Mainwindow handle is found, but the flashobject window is not